# Angular2 - How to use one way databinding to bind to JSON attribute

Tags: json, angular, 2-way-object-databinding

I try to use Angular2's one way databinding to bind an input field value to a JSON property.
The JSON object looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "my name",
    "list": [
      {
        "date": "0101970",
        "list": [
          {
            "timespan": "6-7",
            "entries": [
              {
                "name": ""
              },
              {
                "name": ""
              },
              {
                "name": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to bind the value to a specific `name` attribute of `entries`.
This is how I try to do the on way binding:

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="#category of categories">
        <div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>{{category.name}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngFor="#listentry of category.list">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>{{listentry.date}}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" *ngFor="#shift of listentry.list">
                <div class="row">
                    {{shift.timespan}}
                </div>
                <div class="row" *ngFor="#entry of shift.entries">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" (ngModel)="entry.name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my Component:

```
export class InputComponent {

public categories:Category[];

constructor(private _dataService:DataService) { 
 // ... fetch data from the service here
}
}
```

As I understand the databinding in Angular2 `(ngModel)="attribute"` binds from the view to the model and `[ngModel]="attribute"` binds the other way around.
So, what is wrong with my `<input type="text" class="form-control" (ngModel)="entry.name">` then?

I could use two way databinding instead of course, but I have some other constraints (disabling form elements) which just apply after a button was pressed and not on the user input.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="entry.name">
```

you bind the JSON value to the input.

```
(ngModelChange)="model=$event" updates the model when an `ngModelChange` event is emitted.
```

```
[(ngModel)]="model" binds two-way
```

where `ngModel` is a directive with an

```
@Input() ngModel; // for the [ngModel]="..." bindign
@Output() ngModelChange = EventEmitter(); // for the (ngModelChange)="..." binding
```

together they support the shorthand form

```
[(ngModel)]="model"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but adding `(ngModelChange)="model=$event"` to the input element does not work. Also, there is no error message. As I said earlier, I can't use `[(ngModel)]="model"` due to other constraints. I just want to bind the input to the model. I _don't_ want to update the view if the model changes.

Comment: If you don't want or can't use `ngModel`, then you need to listen to the events of the input element itself like `<input (change)="model=$event.target.value">` (or any other event that input emits like `(blur)`, `(keypress)`, ... `(ngModel)` won't do anything because there is no `ngModel` event. `[(ngModel)]` only works because this is a special form where `[xxx]="model"` and `(xxxChange)="model=$event"` can be combined to `[(xxx)]="model"`

Comment: Thanks! I thought ngModel could do the job... I use (change) now.